# How to initialize a dynamic form using multiple components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to have a form which contains shift for an employee. In the UI, I have a form to specify a shift for each day and **shifts can be dynamically added.**

I want my shift component to be responsible for creating a single shift FormGroup. I am struggling to initialise my parent form or I don't know which component to initialise it in.

Comment: Are you having a separate `Shifts Component` that creates inputs for start/end date? And you want to dynamically add this component inside the `Working Day` template with `ngFor` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `shifts` form array on the parent i.e. `Working day` component and then pass the individual array controls as a `FormGroup` to the child `shift` component.

```
this.parentform = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: new FormControl(),
      shifts: new FormArray([]),
    });

---- Template ----
<app-shift [form]="parentform.get('shifts').controls[index]"></app-shift>
```

By passing `FormGroup` to the child component, you can access its values/validators on the parent also.

**Note:** As you have mentioned, that shifts will be coming from API, you would need to iterate over the shifts array in response & create `FormGroup` with `startDate`/`endDate` properties.

Here is how it would work:

`Shift component`: Take `FormGroup` as an input.

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;

  get shiftForm() {
    return this.form as FormGroup;
  }
```

In the parent component, create the form group & iterate over the `shift` `FormArray.controls`.

`Parent HTML`:

```
  <div formArrayName="shifts">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let shiftForm of shiftsArray.controls; let i = index">
      <app-shift [form]="shiftForm"></app-shift>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

`TS`: On button click/ receiving API response, call `addShift()` method to add a new `FormGroup` in `shifts` control

```
  addShift() {
    const shiftForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: new FormControl(''),
      endDate: new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.shiftsArray.push(shiftForm);
  }
```

**Note:** Recent versions of Angular are strict towards typecasting. Therefore you may need to typecast each `shiftForm` as FormGroup in the parent before passing to the child.

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2nsl1?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) to demonstrate passing `FormGroup` from parent to child.

Comment: You would create the `FormGroups` inside the parent.  If you want child to create the formgroup and send it to parent, then you will emit the form values or the group from child. BUT thats not a good pattern. You should give authority to the parent, rather than the child of creating the form

Comment: You would call the addShift method in the parent when child emits a group. Inside this method, you would create a shift formgroup and add to the array. Just remember to pass the index to the child and emit the index back to avoid duplicate formgroups